# Проблема с Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Запускаю Eclipse, и у меня везде ошибки в проектах. Ошибки в файлах java. Ошибки вот такие:

> R cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type

И т.д. Что случилось? Что можно сделать?

Comment: Ну, тут далеко ходить не надо: [http://hashcode.ru/questions/222472/android-type-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/222472/android-type-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable

Comment: Проверьте на наличие ошибок в layout'ах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй clear project

Answer (score 1):

Это обычная проблема с Эклипс. Нужно её закрыть и снова открыть. Иногда несколько раз. И все ошибки исчезнут.
Я заметила, что если при открытии программы Эклипс курсор остаётся на окне Эклипс, то вероятность появления таких ошибок больше. Поэтому лучше курсор убрать подальше в любую сторону.
Кстати, clear project не поможет.